# Why doesn't this work for a query in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would I write this to wait for the return from getDocs and then console.log?

I'm using react also, I guess I could use a useEffect but still what could be wrong here?

```
const queryGetOneDoc = async (searchForThis, searchField) => {
  const q = query(ref, where(searchField, '==', searchForThis));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
};
```

I'm using await, but I get the error:

> useFirestore.js:135 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
> at queryGetOneDoc (useFirestore.js:135:1)

i have since also tried this (same result):

```
const queryGetOneDoc = async (searchForThis, searchField) => {
  const q = query(ref, where(searchField, '==', searchForThis));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('querySnapshot', snapshot.docs[0].data());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting document:', error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code block assumes that there is a result, which seems to not be true. To solve that, check whether there are any results before accessing them:

```
const q = query(ref, where(searchField, '==', searchForThis));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
  console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
}
```

The second code block makes the same mistake, but on top of that it combines `await` with `then` block which is a common antipattern. Use `await` **or** `then`, not both (in addition to making the same change to ensure there *are* results to display).

Comment: thanks for talking the time here! ok i'll make sure there is a return first. i see. i think there is a return, but i'll figure that out. thanks again for your help.

Comment: ps, you were right, it wasn't returning anythin. it's fixed and works. thank you.